# readlines() and writelines() with read.delim

Tags: r, data-manipulation, readlines, eeglab

I have text files that contain behavioral data from a task. However, the first 18 lines in each file are descriptive information (date, time, ID numbers, etc.) all in a big block of text. The actual column names/data begin on the 19th line. Not an ideal format, but one I have to keep.

While researching the `readlines()` and `writelines()` function, it seems to be what I would need to read in a text file into R to reorganize the data then write it back out as a text file with the same block of text in the first 18 rows. I'm not sure actally how this would work- Do I need to combine `readlines()` and `read.delim()` somehow, or will `readlines()` also read in all my data under the 18th line as if I were to `read.delim(location, skip=18)`?

For reference, here is an example of what a text file I am working with looks like:

```
 # Non-editable header begin --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#  data format...............: continuous
#  setname...................: 200ICAready
#  filename..................: none_specified
#  filepath..................: none_specified
#  nchan.....................: 29
#  pnts......................: 666445
#  srate.....................: 500
#  nevents...................: 1792
#  generated by (bdf)........: 
#  generated by (set)........: 200ICAready
#  reported in ..............: 
#  prog Version..............: 7.0.0
#  creation date.............: 10-Sep-2021 16:21:24
#  user Account..............: 
# 
#  Non-editable header end --------------------------------------------------------------------------------




# item   bepoch   ecode             label         onset           diff       dura   b_flags    a_flags    enable        bin
#                                                 (sec)           (msec)     (msec)    (binary)   (binary)


1       0            13               ""          9.9980          0.00      0.0     00000000     00000000      1    [       ]
2       0             4               ""         10.9990       1001.00      0.0     00000000     00000000      1    [       ]
3       0            10               ""         11.1990        200.00      0.0     00000000     00000000      1    [       ]
4       0            14               ""         11.3990        200.00      0.0     00000000     00000000      1    [       ]
5       0            13               ""         12.7320       1333.00      0.0     00000000     00000000      1    [       ]
6       0             1               ""         13.7320       1000.00      0.0     00000000     00000000      1    [       ]
7       0             7               ""         13.9320        200.00      0.0     00000000     00000000      1    [       ]
```

And here is what the result will look like:

```
 # Non-editable header begin --------------------------------------------------------------------------------

#  data format...............: continuous
#  setname...................: 200ICAready
#  filename..................: none_specified
#  filepath..................: none_specified
#  nchan.....................: 29
#  pnts......................: 666445
#  srate.....................: 500
#  nevents...................: 1792
#  generated by (bdf)........: 
#  generated by (set)........: 200ICAready
#  reported in ..............: 
#  prog Version..............: 7.0.0
#  creation date.............: 10-Sep-2021 16:21:24
#  user Account..............: 
# 
#  Non-editable header end --------------------------------------------------------------------------------




# item   bepoch   ecode             label         onset           diff       dura   b_flags    a_flags    enable        bin
#                                                 (sec)           (msec)     (msec)    (binary)   (binary)


1       0            13               ""          9.9980          0.00      0.0     00000000     00000000      1    [       ]
2       0             4               ""         10.9990       1001.00      0.0     00000000     00000000      1    [       ]
3       0            10               ""         11.1990        200.00      0.0     00000000     00000000      1    [       ]
4       0            15               ""         11.2500       200.00       0.0     00000000     00000000      1    [       ]
5       0            14               ""         11.3990        200.00      0.0     00000000     00000000      1    [       ]
6       0            13               ""         12.7320       1333.00      0.0     00000000     00000000      1    [       ]
7       0             1               ""         13.7320       1000.00      0.0     00000000     00000000      1    [       ]
8       0             19              ""         13.9320        200.00      0.0     00000000     00000000      1    [       ]
```

So, I need R to temporarily store the non-editable header section while I work with the data, then write it out as a text file with the header included.

Edit: I have the header and the data file read in separately and am now trying to find a way to merge them correctly. `c(header, datafile)` and `merge(header, datafile)` did not work.

Comment: I'd just read the header with `readlines`, and the table with `read.delim`. For writing, if performance is not an issue, you can write the bare text file with `write.delim` to a `tempdir()`, then just perform a `readlines` on that one, and use a `c(headerlines, bodylines)` to get the combined result. My data is small :)

Comment: Thanks! I have the header and data read in now, but ```c(header, datafile)``` did not work correctly. When I wrote the text file out all the header lines had merged into the data rows and shifted everything around.

Comment: what is the content of `header` and `datafile` that you have? Can you also show how you want the final expected output to look for this text file ?

Comment: I have the edited '''datafile''' saved out in a .csv file. I had to add a few new rows to the data and fill in some variables under the '''ecode''' and some other columns you see in the original text file example above (2240 rows of data total, excluding column names and the non-editable header). I now need to find a way to automate reading this edited .csv back out to a text file with the big 'non-editable header' in the text file the data originates from, which is different for every subject (it will be the same number of rows, but the ID/Date/Time will all be unique).

Answer (score 1):

Check out my code. It should be very quick.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(data.table)
library(fs)

dataRead = function(file) fread(
  file = file, skip=26, 
  col.names = c("item","bepoch","ecode","label","onset","diff",
                "dura","b_flags","a_flags","enable","bin","bin2"),
  colClasses = c("integer", "integer", "integer", "character",
                 "double", "double", "double", "character",
                 "character", "integer", "character", "character")) %>% 
  as_tibble() %>% 
  mutate(bin = str_c(bin, "    ", bin2)) %>% select(-bin2)
  
width = c(1, 5, 9, 10, 11, 9, 6, 11, 11, 5, 8)
files = dir_ls("txtfiles", regexp = "\\.txt$")
if(length(files)>0){
  for(i in 1:length(files)){
    header = fread(file = files[i], nrows=24, sep = "|", header=FALSE)
    df = dataRead(files[i])
    df = df %>% mutate(bin = "[xxxx]")
    df = df %>% mutate(across(everything(), 
                              ~str_pad(.x, width[which(names(df)==cur_column())])))
    fwrite(header, files[i], append = FALSE, quote = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
    fwrite(df, files[i], append = TRUE, col.names = FALSE, sep = " ", quote = FALSE)
  }
}
```

The program processes every txt file in the txtfiles folder. Reads header and data into `tibble`, mutate the `tibble` then write back to text file.